# MarkLogic, how to add weight to field in cts field word query

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have this piece of code

```
declare variable $a as xs:string := "case-insensitive punctuation-insensitive 
unwildcarded";  

declare variable $b as xs:string* := tokenize($a, ' ');

let $d as cts:query := cts:field-word-query("FULL-CASE-NAME", "complaints", 
$b, 30)
return <q>{$d}</q>
```

which produces this

```
<q>
  <cts:field-word-query weight="30" xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
    <cts:field>FULL-CASE-NAME</cts:field>
    <cts:text xml:lang="en">complaints</cts:text>
    <cts:option>case-insensitive</cts:option>
    <cts:option>punctuation-insensitive</cts:option>
    <cts:option>unwildcarded</cts:option>
  </cts:field-word-query>
</q>
```

but what I want to produce is this

```
<q>
  <cts:field-word-query weight="30" xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
    <cts:field weight="10">FULL-CASE-NAME</cts:field>
    <cts:text xml:lang="en">complaints</cts:text>
    <cts:option>case-insensitive</cts:option>
    <cts:option>punctuation-insensitive</cts:option>
    <cts:option>unwildcarded</cts:option>
  </cts:field-word-query>
</q>
```

the difference is in this line which has an added weight as an attribute

```
<cts:field weight="10">FULL-CASE-NAME</cts:field>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cts:field` just holds the name of the field. The weight (30 in your initial code) is already there, attached as attribute to the `cts:field-word-query`, where it belongs..

HTH!

Comment: You are right, totally misunderstood the meaning of the weight there. Thanks for pointing this out, really helped!